# Android App Creates Incomplete Images

Tags: android, file, bitmap, fileoutputstream

I'm developing an app that combines two bitmaps, where one bitmap is from drawable, and the other is taken from a camera snapshot. However the pictures always end up incomplete. Half the picture is fine, but the other half is gray. Is there a way to make sure that the file is completed before the app moves on with the code? Below is the code that works with writing and saving the file. Thanks

Combine.java

```
protected void createPostcard(byte[] data, File pictureFile, CameraActivity app, Button shareButton,
                              Button newButton) {
    try {
        Bitmap photo    = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        Bitmap splash   = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(app.getResources(), 
                                                    R.drawable.wishsplash), photo.getWidth(), photo.getHeight(), false);
        Bitmap postcard = Bitmap.createBitmap(photo.getWidth(), photo.getHeight(), photo.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas   = new Canvas(postcard);

        canvas.drawBitmap(photo, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(splash, 0, 0, null);
        savePostcard(postcard, pictureFile, app, shareButton, newButton);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }//end catch
}//end createPostcard

/**
 * Saves the postcard
 */
private void savePostcard(Bitmap postcard, File pictureFile, CameraActivity app, Button shareButton, 
                          Button newButton) {

        BitmapDrawable mBitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(postcard);
        Bitmap mNewSaving              = mBitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream   = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        mNewSaving.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        save(byteArray, pictureFile, app);
        shareButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sharebutton);
        newButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newbutton);
        shareButton.setEnabled(true);
        newButton.setEnabled(true);
}//end savePostcard


/**
 * Check if external is available. If not, postcard will be saved in internal.
 * @retun
 */
private void save(byte[] data, File pictureFile, CameraActivity app) {
    try {
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            FileOutputStream fos           = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            imageUri                       = Uri.fromFile(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            imageFile = pictureFile;
            fos.close();
            app.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, 
                                         Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
        } else {
            File cache           = app.getCacheDir();
            File internalPic     = new File(cache, pictureFile.getName());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(internalPic);
            imageUri             = Uri.fromFile(internalPic);
            imageFile            = internalPic;
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        }//end else
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("FILENOTFOUND");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOEXCEPTION");
    }//end catch
}//end getStorage
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    public Bitmap PutoverBmp(Bitmap all, Bitmap scaledBorder) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    final int width = bmp.getWidth(); // bmp is your main Bitmap
    final int height = bmp.getHeight();
    patt = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, true);
    Bitmap mutableBitmap = patt.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
    scaledBorder = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(border, width, height, true);
    paint.setAlpha(100);
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBorder, 0, 0, paint);
    return mutableBitmap;

}
```

simply call this `Bitmap combine = (bmp , yourOtherBitmap);`

Comment: Thank you for the advice. However now I'm getting an OutOfMemoryError, Heap Size=49187KB, Allocated=42138KB, Limit=49152KB. This seems to happen on the line that starts with 'patt'

Comment: you'll have to inSampleSize the bitmap first otherwise it will give you out of memory.